# Let's get critical: Apr 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Computational Science Stack Exchange](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Linear programming with matrix constraints](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10918/linear-programming-with-matrix-constraints)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Least squares approximation question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/11153/least-squares-approximation-question)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Does the covariance matrix in Least Squares depend upon the input data?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/11096/does-the-covariance-matrix-in-least-squares-depend-upon-the-input-data)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Estimating hardware error probability](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10946/estimating-hardware-error-probability)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Courant Friedrichs Lewy condition - how to get it?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10993/courant-friedrichs-lewy-condition-how-to-get-it)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Fibonacci, variation on the theme](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/11055/fibonacci-variation-on-the-theme)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Convex objective function of matrix with prescribed determinant and trace](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10908/convex-objective-function-of-matrix-with-prescribed-determinant-and-trace)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [last column of SPD matrix given it's spectral decomposition](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/11068/last-column-of-spd-matrix-given-its-spectral-decomposition)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Crouzeix-Raviart Finite Element](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/11114/crouzeix-raviart-finite-element)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Nodal DG method and limiters for hyperbolic conservation laws](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/11083/nodal-dg-method-and-limiters-for-hyperbolic-conservation-laws)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 3)

---